# Do spells persist past transmigration?

Tags: disgaea

Do spells learned naturally persist after transmigration?

By standing next to a pupil, a master gets access to all spells the pupil has. By leveling that spell from 0 to 1, the master gets it "permanently". Will the master still have that spell after transmigration?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Skill EXP lost during transmigration doesn't cause the level to go lower than 1, the spell will be kept. Transmigrating as a Genius keeps 95% of skill experience.